# How to change xticks and yticks of a log-log plot after ScalarFormatter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have this code:

```
 # Modules I import 

    import matplotlib
    if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
        print('no display found. Using non-interactive Agg backend')
        matplotlib.use('Agg')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
    from pylab import *

# My Variables to plot

    ideal_walltime_list = [135.82, 67.91, 33.955, 16.9775, 8.48875]
    cores_plotting = [16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
    time_plotting = [135.82, 78.69, 50.62, 46.666, 42.473]

# My plotting part
    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(cores_plotting, time_plotting, c='r', label='System wall time')
    plt.plot(cores_plotting, ideal_walltime_list, c='k', label='Ideal Wall time')

    plt.title('109bEdec_test')
    plt.ylabel('Wall time (s)')

    plt.xlabel('Cores')
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xscale('log')

    ax = gca().xaxis
    ax.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
    ax.set_minor_formatter(ScalarFormatter())

    ay = gca().yaxis
    ay.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
    ay.set_minor_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
    plt.savefig('109bEdec_test' + '.png',dpi=1800)


    plt.show()
```

When I run this code my plot look like this:

[image]

However, I need my x-axis and y-axis to display the ticks corresponding to my cores_plotting variable and not all those numbers that have bad formatting.
I have tried using:

```
plt.xticks(cores_plotting)
plt.yticks(cores_plotting)
```

But no success.

Also I tried:

```
plt.xticks(cores_plotting, ('16', '32', '64', '128', '256'))
plt.yticks(cores_plotting, ['16', '32', '64', '128', '256'])
```

But no success neither. Right now I just need to have the cores_plotting items as my X and Y ticks.

My python version is 3.6.5 and my Matplotlib version is 3.0.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first put the custom ticks which will act as the major ticks and then hide the minor ticks. You need to create an axis handle `ax` to access the minor ticks. Please check the strings you are using for your y-ticklabels.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.scatter(cores_plotting, time_plotting, c='r', label='System wall time')
plt.plot(cores_plotting, ideal_walltime_list, c='k', label='Ideal Wall time')

# Rest of your code here

ax.set_yticks(cores_plotting) 
ax.set_yticklabels(['16', '32', '64', '128', '256'])

ax.set_xticks(cores_plotting) 
ax.set_xticklabels(['16', '32', '64', '128', '256'])

for xticks in ax.xaxis.get_minor_ticks():
    xticks.label1.set_visible(False)
    xticks.set_visible(False)

for yticks in ax.yaxis.get_minor_ticks():
    yticks.label1.set_visible(False)
    yticks.set_visible(False)
```

**Matplotlib version issue**

It seems that the following commands does not work in `matplotlib` 3+ version and throws

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` error.

In such case, use the above method to assign the ticks and the tick labels.

```
plt.xticks(cores_plotting, ['16', '32', '64', '128', '256']);
plt.yticks(cores_plotting, ['16', '32', '64', '128', '256'])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. I tried your code and it has this error:   
 plt.xticks(cores_plotting, ('16', '32', '64', '128', '256'));

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @ananvodo: Let me know if it works now. I juts copied the `(   )` thing from your question

Comment: nopr. It still says: plt.xticks(cores_plotting, ['16', '32', '64', '128', '256']);

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable. This problem persisted all the time I used xticks and yticks

Comment: Can you try saving the list in a variable as `ticks=['16', '32', '64', '128', '256']` and then use `plt.xticks(cores_plotting,ticks)`

Comment: You can also try : `ax.set_xticks(cores_plotting)` and then `ax.set_xticklabels(['16', '32', '64', '128', '256'])`

Comment: for the first suggestion ticks=[....] the error is: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: for the x.set_xticks(cores_plotting) is says: AttributeError: 'XAxis' object has no attribute 'set_xticks'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186279/discussion-between-ananvodo-and-bazingaa).